# Node.js, Express.js, Angular.js: Hosting my own API

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-web-services, api, express

I am new to coding and I have a question about a small app that I created with angular.js that makes a post request to another express.js app.
It's a simple parentheses balance checker, you can find the whole code here:
**https://github.com/OGsoundFX/parentheseschecker**

The **FrontEnd-Refactored** folder contains the **Angular.js** app and the **APItesting** contains the **express.js API**.

The app is working, but I have only been using it locally. The API runs on localhost:3000 and the app on localhost:8080

But what if I want to make it public? How would I go about it? I don't really know where to start.
Where to host a node.js of express.js app. I read about **AWS**, would that be good, or are there better services?

I have a **Wordpress** website hosted on **https://www.mddhosting.com/** but that wouldn't work, right?

My Angular app is calling the api locally at the moment, so I will probably have to change the API link that it is fetching:

**ApiService.js**

```
function ApiService($http) {
    API = '//localhost:3000/parentheses';
    this.getUser = (entry) => {
        return $http
            .post(API, { string: entry} )
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function (reason) {
                // error
            })
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('ApiService', ApiService);
```

In my API **server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

I will definitely have to change `API = '//localhost:3000/parentheses';` in my AngularJS app, but should I change `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;` ?

I just need a little push start to help me clear some confusion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you use application-level environment variables For example: To define the BASE_URL of your site for development and production separately. Doing so you don't have to make any configuration changes when you go live, it is a one-time process.

And if you are looking for free hosting services for pet projects Heroku is good and if you really want to make site go live for the end-users you may go for AWS EC2 instance or Heroku paid service both are good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds good! I will have a look at setting application-level environment variables, as a start and take it from there
I will get back to you, thanks!